# Spring Boot - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I have created a spring boot application with Websocket.
Everything works really fine except test.

I've wrote simple test to check DB connection like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebsocketConfig.class)
public class MongoDbTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRoomRepository;

    @Test
    void dbConnectionTest() {
        List<MyObject> objects = myRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println(objects .size());
    }
}
```

My application runs perfectly But when running my springboot test, I've faced the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverEndpointExporter' defined in com.myApp.chat.common.conf.WebsocketConfig: jakarta.websocket.server.ServerContainer not available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:118) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:88) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65) ~[na:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74) ~[gradle-worker.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jakarta.websocket.server.ServerContainer not available
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.afterPropertiesSet(ServerEndpointExporter.java:107) ~[spring-websocket-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 105 common frames omitted
```

And here's my configuration class for websocket.

```
@Configuration
public class WebsocketConfig extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static volatile BeanFactory context;

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException {
        return context.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that the configuration file might be the problem.
what is wrong with it? and what can I do to resolve the error?